# Job 28:7-11 is about the benefits of praying and speaking in tongues

Tags: job, spiritual-gifts, prayer

Benny Hinn mentions in this youtube video -->(   https://youtu.be/mX_Ts0jAFNU?t=823   ) that Job 28:7-11 is about the benefits of praying and speaking in tongues:

> ( Job 28:7-11 )
>
> 7 “The path no bird of prey knows, Nor has the falcon’s eye caught
> sight of it. 8 “The [a]proud beasts have not trodden it, Nor has the
> fierce lion passed over it. 9 “He puts his hand on the flint; He
> overturns the mountains at the [b]base. 10 “He hews out channels
> through the rocks, And his eye sees anything precious. 11 “He dams up
> the streams from [c]flowing, And what is hidden he brings out to the
> light.

I thought Benny Hinn's assessment of the aforementioned passage was interesting.
LOL, some of you who have a NonCharismatic, NonPentecostal or especially a Cessationist Christian background may emphatically disagree with the above assessment.
In any case, Could someone please provide feedback on his assessment, and also provide their perspectives on said bible passage?

Comment: This site is for exegesis, whereas what Hinn is doing is homiletics.  You can use the same passage in many different homiletic applications, but that does not mean that this is what the passage "is about". This is especially true of poetry (prophecy is also poetry).

Comment: This passage never mentions speaking in tongues, spiritual gifts or even the Holy Spirit, and there is nothing here to connect it to that phenomenon.

Answer (score 2):

From my reading, the overall theme of this passage is about God uncovering the hidden things.

### Determining a text

With Job, there are numerous textual problems in both the LXX and the MT as well as difficulties in translation. I recommend Pope's Anchor Yale Bible Job[1], which incorporates the Dead Sea Scrolls and is well regarded. Here is Pope's translation for verses 7-11:

```
  The path no bird of prey knows,
  No falcon’s eye has seen.

  The proud beasts have not trodden it,
  No serpent passed over it.

  He puts his hand to the flint,
  Overturns mountains at the base.

  In the rocks he hews out channels,
  His eye sees every precious thing.

  The sources of the rivers he probes,
  Brings hidden things to light.
```

[1] Pope, M. H. (2008). Job: Introduction, translation, and notes (Vol. 15, p. 197). New Haven;  London: Yale University Press.

### Interpreting the passage

```
  The path no bird of prey knows,
  No falcon’s eye has seen.
```

So there is an invisible path (or way of life, journey, process) hidden from the natural eyes (birds have the best eyes and can see everything). In the wisdom literature this is generally the hidden path of Wisdom.

But also birds in the bible are often symbolic of spirits (they fly through the heavens), with unclean birds (like vultures) symbolic of evil spirits.Thus we could also take this to mean that there is a path hidden from evil spirits as well as from natural eyes.

```
  The proud beasts have not trodden it,
  No serpent passed over it.
```

In addition to the spirits, the brute men (proud beasts, literally "sons of pride") are not able to walk on this path and the devil (the serpent) cannot walk on it either. Sons of pride is also a reference to Leviathan in Job 41.26. Serpent could also be lion, but as we are talking about unclean animals, the serpent is preferred.  So far, the second couplet reinforces the first of both natural/spiritual blindness to the secret path of wisdom.

```
  He puts his hand to the flint,
  Overturns mountains at the base.
```

This begins a description of all the things that men do to find gold or precious ores, digging into the mountain, but God is able to overturn mountains at the base and find what is underneath them. E.g. the path is visible to God.

```
  In the rocks he hews out channels,
  His eye sees every precious thing.
```

Continuing with God, who sees every precious hidden thing, whereas the brute beasts and birds do not.

```
  The sources of the rivers he probes,
  Brings hidden things to light.
```

Now here is the punchline. Those hidden things that God sees -- the secret path of wisdom -- he brings it to light! Then we can all see it.

So I am reminded of Matt 13. In verse 16-17 Christ states:

> But blessed are your eyes, for they see, and your ears, for they hear.
> For truly, I say to you, many prophets and righteous people longed to
> see what you see, and did not see it, and to hear what you hear, and
> did not hear it.

And after he gives the parable, he tells his disciples even more:

> Matthew 13:35
>
> “I will open My mouth in parables; *I will utter things hidden since
> the foundation of the world.*”

Which is a quotation of Psalm 78:2-4

> Psalm 78:2-4
>
> I will open my mouth in a parable: I will utter dark sayings of old:
> Which we have heard and known, And our fathers have told us. We will
> not hide them from their children, Shewing to the generation to come
> The praises of the LORD, and his strength, And his wonderful works
> that he hath done.

Or 1 Peter 1
In verse 10-12:

> Concerning this salvation, **the prophets who prophesied about the
> grace that was to be yours searched and inquired carefully**,
> inquiring what person or time the Spirit of Christ in them was
> indicating when he predicted the sufferings of Christ and the
> subsequent glories. It was revealed to them that they were serving not
> themselves but you, in the things that have now been announced to you
> through those who preached the good news to you by the Holy Spirit
> sent from heaven, **things into which angels long to look**.

and 18-21:

> Forasmuch as ye know that ye were not redeemed with corruptible
> things, as silver and gold, from your vain conversation received by
> tradition from your fathers; But with the precious blood of Christ, as
> of a lamb without blemish and without spot: **Who verily was
> foreordained before the foundation of the world, but was manifest in
> these last times for you**, Who by him do believe in God, that raised
> him up from the dead, and gave him glory; that your faith and hope
> might be in God.

Or Romans 16.25-26

> Now to him that is of power to stablish you according to my gospel,
> and the preaching of Jesus Christ, **according to the revelation of the
> mystery, which was kept secret since the world began, But now is made
> manifest, and by the scriptures of the prophets, according to the
> commandment of the everlasting God, made known to all nations for the
> obedience of faith**:

Thus one interpretation of the "hidden path of Wisdom" would be the gospel, especially the "sufferings" of Christ, and then by consequence of our union with him, our own suffering (1 Peter 1.6-9).

So we could interpret this to mean that the evil spirits could not comprehend that the victory of God would come about through the suffering Christ, this was hidden from the foundations of the world, locked in veins of gold and precious stones, symbolic of things purified in the pressure and fire of suffering, and even the Angels (good spirits) longed to look into and understand these things, but it was hidden from them as well, but was revealed by God to us.

### Speaking in tongues?

Hinn is also associating the vultures with evil spirits and the veins of gold with the hidden things of God that are being revealed. But he is not associating the proud beasts with sensual men and does not really try to carefully go over this passage. For him, the revelation of the hidden things are accomplished through speaking in tongues, so that it bypasses the natural mind, which is consistent with the path being hidden from the flesh.

I think this is a reasonable example of a homiletical use of Biblical poetry, as long as Hinn does not say that this is the only type of revelation performed by God.

It would be nice if he elaborated a bit more, and he also might have mentioned the gospel somewhere in there, even just once. Christ, Paul and Peter seemed to find time to work that into whatever topic they were discussing, but which of our own sermons are as good as these?

Suffering, also, is key here - as this is the reason why the world cannot see it, and the evil spirits could not find it.